# how do i use inputfields and change the values

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have this code after asking some questions and now I don't get any errors but this still does not work

**i have a input field which has 2 components and i take the text component and try to change the value of the text but when i run the project whenever i type in the input field it does not change the text at all**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TextRecstriction : MonoBehaviour
{

    public Text text;

    public string a = "a";
    public string b = "b";
    public string c = "c";
    public string d = "d";
    public string e = "e";
    public string f = "f";
    public string g = "g";
    public string h = "h";
    public string i = "i";
    public string j = "j";
    public string k = "k";
    public string l = "l";
    public string m = "m";
    public string n = "n";
    public string o = "o";
    public string p = "p";
    public string q = "q";
    public string r = "r";
    public string s = "s";
    public string t = "t";
    public string u = "u";
    public string v = "v";
    public string w = "w";
    public string x = "x";
    public string y = "y";
    public string z = "z";

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        string textoncanvas = text.text;
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(a))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(a, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(b))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(b, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(c))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(c, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(d))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(d, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(e))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(e, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(f))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(f, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(g))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(g, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(h))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(h, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(i))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(i, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(j))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(j, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(k))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(k, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(l))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(l, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(m))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(m, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(n))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(n, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(o))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(o, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(p))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(p, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(q))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(q, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(r))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(r, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(s))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(s, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(t))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(t, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(u))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(u, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(v))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(v, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(w))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(w, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(x))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(x, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(y))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(y, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;
        }
        if (textoncanvas.Contains(z))
        {
            textoncanvas.Replace(z, "");
            text.text = textoncanvas;                
        }
    }
}
```

> pls help me

Comment: Hm...I don't really understand what you're trying to do with this code honestly. InputField component are built-in component that already handles the fact that when you press "g", it add the letter "g" to the text property. What are you trying to achieve exactly ?

Answer (score 0):

If this is an [`InputField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-InputField.html) you do **not** want to directly access the `Text` component but rather go via `InputField.text`!

Besides that if you want only a certain alphabet of allowed characters then configure this via the Inspector! Set `ContentType` to e.g. either numeric (=> only numbers are allowed) or custom and configure the allowed characters according to your need. What you currently do is a huge waste of performance

> *Content Type*
>
> Define the type(s) of characters that your input field accepts
>
> - Standard: Any character can be entered.
> - Autocorrected: The autocorrection determines whether the input tracks unknown words and suggests a more suitable replacement candidate to the user, replacing the typed text automatically unless the user explicitly overrides the action.
> - Integer Number: Allow only whole numbers to be entered.
> - Decimal Number: Allow only numbers and a single decimal point to be entered.
> - Alphanumeric: Allow both letters and numbers. Symbols cannot be entered.
> - Name: Automatically capitalizes the first letter of each word. Note that the user can circumvent the capitalization rules using the Delete key.
> - Email Address: Allows you to enter an Alphanumeric string consisting of a maximum of one `@` sign. periods/baseline dots cannot be entered next to each other.
> - Password*: Conceals the characters inputed with an asterisk. Allows symbols.
> - Pin: Conceals the characters inputed with an asterisk. Only allows only whole numbers to be entered.
> - Custom: Allows you to customise the `Line Type`, `Input Type`, `Keyboard Type` and `Character Validation`.

---

Besides that for what you are doing you would probably rather use a [`Regex.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace?view=net-6.0#System_Text_RegularExpressions_Regex_Replace_System_String_System_String_System_String_) like e.g.

```
text.text = Regex.Replace(text.text, "[a-z]", "");
```

which will remove any character between `a` and `z`.